# silverlight clienthttp certificate error

Tags: silverlight, certificate

We are using clientHttp stack in our Silverlight app. The server hosting the web service has self-signed certificate. I am able to make service call when using browserHttp stack. But if I change to clientHTTP stack the request doesnt even go to the server. This happens on Firefox and Chrome. On IE both clientHTTP and browserHttp stack work fine. Our server side is java based(CXF).

What possible workaround can I do to make clientHTTP work on Firefox? Is there any possible way to make clientHTTP ignore certificate validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but it's probably a matter of the client not trusting the issuer of the server certificate.  I have seen the behavior you described, but out of browser, until I added the issuer's root CA certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities node of the local computer certificate store.